# Why is my ListPlot rounding up fractions?

Tags: plotting, curated-data

I'm trying to create a `ListPlot` that compares a country's poverty fraction with its cellular phone fraction.

I'm using this to create the table.

```
povresults = Table[Tooltip[{i, CountryData[i, "PovertyFraction"],
                            CountryData[i, "CellularPhones"]/CountryData[i, "Population"]},
                   i], {i, listOfCountries}]
```

I get good output. Investigating `povresults` shows

```
{{Afghanistan, 0.53,0.221735per person}, {Algeria,0.23,0.85049per person}, ...
```

But when I run a chart

```
ListPlot[povresults, PlotRange -> All]
```

I get this chart. It seems to have rounded the results to 1 and 3. What am I doing wrong?

[image: my chart]

Comment: I'm surprised `ListPlot[]` even did something! Note that `ListPlot[]` expects to be given points as input, but you still have the names of the countries in your list. In what axis are they supposed to correspond to?

Comment: They corrospond to the 'i' in Tootltip. I don't think that's the problem. Am still learning through.

Comment: Your initial way of using `Tooltip[]` was the problem, then; `Tooltip[{CountryData[i, "PovertyFraction"], CountryData[i, "CellularPhones"]/CountryData[i, "Population"]}, CanonicalName[i]]` works nicely (note that the name is a *separate argument* from the point!) Thus: `ListPlot[Select[Table[Tooltip[{CountryData[i, "PovertyFraction"], CountryData[i, "CellularPhones"]/CountryData[i, "Population"]}, CanonicalName[i]], {i, CountryData["Countries"]}], FreeQ[#, Missing] &]]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is code based on yours that I think produces the graph you want:

```
listOfCountries = CountryData[#, "Name"] & /@ CountryData["Countries"];

povresults = 
  Table[{i, CountryData[i, "PovertyFraction"], 
    CountryData[i, "CellularPhones"]/
     CountryData[i, "Population"]}, {i, listOfCountries}];

povresults = Select[povresults, FreeQ[#, Missing] &];

ListPlot[Map[Tooltip[Rest[#], First[#]] &, povresults], 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 FrameLabel -> {"PovertyFraction", "CellularPhones / Population"}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But if I cut and paste that code in I get a similar (but different problem). All the points are lined up with 1.0 and are multicolored?

Comment: I've added a screen grab above.

Comment: @LucyHattersley I corrected the code in my answer. (I had some redundant column extraction.)

Comment: Ah great! It works now. Will go over your code and learn how you're extracting the data. Thanks ever so much.

Answer (score 7):

**This is J.M.s answer**. I post it as it nicely illustrates  "flagging" countries and tooltips.

```
Graphics[Select[Table[Tooltip[Inset[CountryData[i, "Flag"],
         {CountryData[i, "PovertyFraction"],
          CountryData[i, "CellularPhones"]/CountryData[i, "Population"]} //
         QuantityMagnitude, Automatic, Scaled[1/50]], CanonicalName[i]],
         {i, CountryData["Countries"]}], FreeQ[#, Missing] &], 
         AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Frame -> True, 
         FrameLabel -> {"PovertyFraction", "CellularPhones / Population"}, 
         GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Thin, Dotted, Opacity[1/5]], 
         ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: @J.M. I just thought this was nice. If you don't want I will happily delete.  :)

Comment: Okay, I have tweaked the code a bit; I don't have nice screencapping software, so can you do that favor for me? :)

Comment: @J.M. I will happily delete after you have tweaked. I just think it is useful to illustrate the diversity and customizability....:)

Comment: @J.M. it you write the answer I can edit and add short gif and delete mine.

Comment: @J.M. just saw you edited it. Am scraping now

Comment: This is concise code that produces an informative plot. It is fairly impressive, if it is considered in the context of comparisons with other systems, like Matlab or R.

Comment: @Anton, my first thought was: "why the hell should I have to wade through points", followed by "wait, `Inset[]` is built-in now" and "why not let the flags be markers?" ;) Also, the surprise is that even tho the flags are not rendered in detail, there is still a sufficient amount of features present that somebody looking at the graph could still pick out the country s/he wants to see.

Comment: @AntonAntonov I agree and  J.M.  continues to teach me (& others). Anton your answer was the launching pad. This one of the things I most enjoy about MSE. But as my partner never ceases to remind me, it is not all about me.  :)

Comment: @J.M. worth the tweaks...Estonia has a high cell phone per capita and low poverty...thanks :)

Comment: @J.M. Right, I spotted Bulgaria and Russia almost immediately. (Being next to each other, I guess...)

Comment: @ubpdqn Hm, your partner probably does not like the TV series "House" and you do...

Answer (score 3):

Just to illustrate `DynamicWrapper` using Anton Antonov's code:

```
pr = PadRight[Partition[povresults[[All, 1]], UpTo[6]]] /. {0 -> ""};
Grid[pr, Frame -> All];
f = DynamicModule[{col = Black}, 
    DynamicWrapper[Dynamic[Style[#, col, Bold]], 
     If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], col = Red;
      pos = {#2, #3[[1]]}, col = Black; pos = {}]]] &;
Column[
 {ListPlot[{#2, #3} & @@@ povresults, 
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Dynamic@Point[pos]}, 
   ImageSize -> 600, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Poverty Fraction", "Cell phone per person"}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Kartika", 12}],
  Grid[PadRight[Partition[f @@@ povresults, UpTo[4]]] /. {0 -> ""}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Kartika"
     , 12}]
  }, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Very useful (+1, of course). I was thinking that it is hard to locate a particular country just by browsing the tooltiptips.

Comment: @AntonAntonov thanks...just as `Tooltip` (which I should have added as you did), allows working out "winners" and "losers", sometimes user may want to know where their country of interest is in the pack...all fun:)

Comment: I'd actually just have ditched `ListPlot[]` altogether: `Graphics[Select[Table[Tooltip[Inset[CountryData[i, "Flag"], {CountryData[i, "PovertyFraction"], CountryData[i, "CellularPhones"]/CountryData[i, "Population"]} // QuantityMagnitude, Automatic, 1/50], CanonicalName[i]], {i, CountryData["Countries"]}], FreeQ[#, Missing] &], AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Frame -> True]`.

Comment: @J.M. why don't you post that as an answer, esp like the flag. Thank you for showing me `CanonicalName`.The depth of my ignorance never ceases to dismay me. :)